# Regression ML model: Data Augmentation

Tags: regression, machine-learning, random-forest, noise, data-augmentation

I'm currently working on data augmentation to my regression problem, and a (possible) solution that came to my mind was to add a perturbed dataset to the original dataset, and hence double the training samples. Here what I've done:

for a feature $X$, with $n$ samples and standard deviation $sigma_X$, I generated some noise following a Gaussian distribution: `noise = np.random.normal(mean = 0, std = 0.1*sigma_X, df.shape)`.
Then, the perturbed feature is defined as `perturbed_X = X + noise`. The standard deviation fraction $0.1$ was chosen in order to be small enough to keep the overall correlations between the parameters on my dataset and also to be large enough to add variety to the augmented data.

I did this procedure for the training set only, so the test set consists only of the original data.

My questions are:

-Is this a good technique?

-Where does it fail?

-What can I do to improve this method?

I'm asking this because I'm in a dillema with one of my coleagues: he says that this method changes the distribution of my parameters, once they do not follow a Gaussian distribution, but I argue that although the noise is Gaussian distributed, the noisy data is not. Because what I'm essencially doing is adding some small random number to each datapoint. In the end the distribution is basically the same.

If anyone is interested in the distribution of the original data versus the perturbed data, I'm letting a link to the [.pdf with the plots](https://docdro.id/TKE6ls9)

What do you think? If so, where/how does this method fail?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about the response variable? We got more readings of $X$ but we care for $y = f(X)$ right?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your answer, but the noise was also added to the targets. so the training set consists of noisy features and targets

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, it was unclear based on the post. Effectively what is happening is a ridge-regression at this point then. We are biasing our coefficients towards 0. Your colleague is correct you are changing the distribution of the model parameters. Also note that while you get "more data" these are not IID samples any more so in case of using any "degrees of freedom" based methodology is used, then it has to be adjusted (downwards). Use a (application-informed) generative model if you wish to get "more data".